# Is there a way to stop a fragment 1 going to fragment 2 when I swipe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

is there a way to stop fragment 1 going to fragment 2 when I swipe right/left
I noticed recently that if I swipe left my fragment changes from 1 to 2.

I searched on web but I couldn't find an answer

Edit:

My code for adapter

```
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter



    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment_Sign_In_To_Firebase(), "Firebase Sign In");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment_Create_Account(), "Create Account");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment_Verify_Email(), "Verify Email");


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id_chat);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

ViewPaggerAdapter class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> lstFragment = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> lstTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return lstFragment.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lstTitles.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return lstTitles.get(position);
}

public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    lstFragment.add(fragment);
    lstTitles.add(title);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe post some code so that people can get more of an idea of what you mean?

Comment: @Ashish my class extends FragmentPagerAdapter not ViewPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I can see your question is not having a proper query on what you are searching for exactly ,I think you are talking about ViewPager*

```
 public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } }
```

Use this in your XML

```
<mypackage.CustomViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

OR SIMPLE ADD THIS LINE

```
myViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
```

Comment: I have a fragmentPagerAdapter not ViewPager